# How to remove the user name saved in Chrome form?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I'm using Chrome to log-in to the Joomla 2.5.26 administrator.
After recently changing the administrator username, every time I load the joomla-25-site.com/administrator log-in form, it still remembers the old admin user name.
I deleted all cookies associated with this domain and restarted the browser.
But the user name still appears in the login form.
How can I remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's applies to any forms

1. When you want to remove suggestions saved in form:

   Click on empty form

   Put mouse pointer on given suggestion and hit <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>
2. When you want to remove saved `username` and `password`:

   For  `Chrome Browser`

   `chrome://settings/passwords`

   and delete saved password

   Manual path for this resource is:

   Chrome menu > Settings > Show advanced settings... (on the very bottom) > `Passwords and Forms` section -> Manage passwords

OR with new material design since v59
Chrome menu -> Setting menu on the left top corner -> Expand Advanced -> Paswords and forms -> Manage passwords
[image]

Comment: chrome password manager worked for me, thanks ! shift+delete didn't work, even if i mark it, after refreshing it comes back

Comment: Shift+Delete works only for suggestions what are shown after clicking empty form:)

Comment: Just for record, on the Yosemite, i had to use: `shift` + `function` + `delete`.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 I had to use shift + alt + delete.

Answer (score 5):

FOR MAC:

Mouse over the item you want to select.

`shift` + `fn` + `delete`

or, if you are using a full keyboard, you can use the "delete" key above the arrows, next to "end" and below "fn" (combined with shift)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running multiple accounts on Chrome, you will need to delete autofill for both accounts in order to clear autofill for one on of them.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> on an active item in a list.